# How do I solve a c memory access violation with a pointer dereference

Tags: c, memory-management, access-violation

Using this method:

```
void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size)
{
    size_t n = size + alignment - sizeof(void*);
    bool zero = false;
    char* p = (char*)(zero ? calloc(1, n) : malloc(sizeof(void*) + n));

    if (p)
    {
        size_t remainder = ((size_t)p) % alignment;
        size_t offset = alignment - remainder;
        char* ret = p + (unsigned char)offset;

        // store how many extra bytes we allocated in the byte just before the pointer we return
        *((unsigned char*)(ret - 1)) = offset;

        return (void*)ret;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I am getting Exception thrown 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFF87FA06FF at the line "`*((unsigned char*)(ret - 1)) = offset;`".

How do I fix "`*((unsigned char*)(ret - 1)) = offset;`" to avoid this access violation error?

I am using the Tbman - Fast and Easy Memory Manager to implement a memory manager and I was having trouble finding an aligned_alloc method to use with it.

I found the aligned_alloc method I showed in the description online but ran into this access violation error when running a test from the Tbman memory manager code.

Here is the original code I found online, before I started messing with it.

```
void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size, bool zero) {
    size_t request_size = size + alignment;
    char* buf = (char*)(zero ? calloc(1, request_size) : malloc(request_size));

    size_t remainder = ((size_t)buf) % alignment;
    size_t offset = alignment - remainder;
    char* ret = buf + (unsigned char)offset;

    // store how many extra bytes we allocated in the byte just before the
    // pointer we return
    *(unsigned char*)(ret - 1) = offset;

    return (void*)ret;
}
```

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: For anyone interested if your in windows and cannot find aligned_alloc() method. I found that you can use the _aligned_malloc() method defined in malloc.h. In the tbman.c file I replaced the aligned_alloc() method with _aligned_malloc(). I still have more testing to do to make sure I can fully use this with my project.

Answer (score 1):

- `size_t n = size + alignment - sizeof(void*);` This doesn't make any sense. You should allocate something like:

  ```
  size_t n = (size % alignment) ? (size + alignment) : size;
  ```

  As in, over-allocate to suit the alignment requirement.
- `malloc(sizeof(void*) ...` in general doesn't make any sense. You should allocate a size in bytes, not the size of a pointer, which will be 4 or 8 bytes or such.
- Casting to/from `void*` in C is pointless and mostly serves to make the reader suspect that you are actually compiling in C++.

If you are trying to allocate extra room to compensate for underlying malloc/calloc not returning an aligned address (as per `alignment`), well no can do. You can't solve that by over-allocating, sneaking in some "heap segment header" and returning a pointer some bytes into the allocated chunk, because your function must return a pointer which can be passed to `free()`. Or otherwise you'd have to design a matching `aligned_free()`.

The good news is that malloc/calloc will already return an aligned address as per "fundamental alignment", which is the maximum supported alignment by the compiler. So no strange hack is necessary.

Is there a reason why you can't use standard C `aligned_alloc()`?

Comment: I added more to what I posted, also I am programming on windows 10 and I was having trouble finding the aligned_alloc method. I am using cmake to build with visual studio 2022 and the aligned_alloc was not found.

Comment: @dustinwatson You need a crt/standard lib which was updated during the past 11 years, so Visual Studio won't do. Consider switching to a conforming C compiler. In the meantime maybe you can use non-standard `_aligned_malloc()` which will only work on compilers using Microsoft's ancient crt.